# Nested mapcars in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I want to combine all posible combinations of  two lists and for that I use mapcar

```
CL-USER> (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (mapcar #'(lambda (y) (list x y)) '(aa bb cc dd))) '(a b c))

(((A AA) (A BB) (A CC) (A DD)) ((B AA) (B BB) (B CC) (B DD))
 ((C AA) (C BB) (C CC) (C DD)))
```

the answer is correct but I get a nested list, how can I solve this. I would not like to flatten that list one level, I'm doing a bad use of mapcar but I cannot figure how to solve this

Comment: `MAPCAN` (or `ALEXANDRIA:MAPPEND`) will concatenate the results into one list.

Comment: You want to compute the cartesian product: `(alexandria:map-product  #'list '(a b c) '(aa bb cc dd))`

Comment: yes at the end I want to construct that function, thanks

Comment: You can also go with the iteration, in alternative to high-level functions: `(loop for x in '(a b c) nconc (loop for y in '(aa bb cc) collect (list x y)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the top-level [`mapcar` with `mapcan`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm) and you are golden:

```
(mapcan (lambda (x) 
          (mapcar (lambda (y) (list x y))
                  '(aa bb cc dd)))
        '(a b c))
==> ((A AA) (A BB) (A CC) (A DD) 
     (B AA) (B BB) (B CC) (B DD)
     (C AA) (C BB) (C CC) (C DD))
```